# How to access canvas context in React

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs

I made a [color picker](http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/KdjddW?editors=001) with React and Canvas. Currently the components are rendered in React and canvas is done with vanilla javascript. I'd like to two to mesh more, so I want the click events to be handled with React.

For example, this

```
colorStrip.addEventListener("click", click, false);

function click(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  rgbaColor = 'rgba(' + imageData[0] + ',' + imageData[1] + ',' + imageData[2] + ',1)';
  fillGradient();
}
```

I would hope would be able to translate to this

```
var ColorPicker = React.createClass({
  colorStripClick: function() {
    //handle click events here
  },
  render: function() {
    var styles = {
      opacity: this.props.isVisible ? '1' : '0'
    };
    return(
      <div id="color-picker" style={styles}>
        <canvas id="color-block" height="150" width="150"></canvas>
        <canvas id="color-strip" height="150" width="30" onClick={this.colorStripClick}></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But that doesn't work because I don't know how to access `context`. How can I get access to the canvas properties with React? Is there a way to access it before the click?

**UPDATE**

I used David's answer but I was getting errors by putting a function in `ref` so I did `ref="canvasBlock"` and `ref="canvasStrip"` instead and then assigned the context in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I made a similar project https://github.com/gibbok/react-color-picker-palette you can look on how to access your context in this example for function getDrawingContex() {: https://github.com/gibbok/react-color-picker-palette/blob/master/ColorPickerPalette.jsx

Comment: in the function by David you have to add "if (c == null)" I guess because you get the element reference just once on mount, not on rerenders.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add a `ref` function attribute on the `canvas` element:

```
<canvas id="color-strip" ref={(c) => this.context = c.getContext('2d')} height="...
```

Then you’ll have access to the context through `this.context`:

```
colorStripClick: function() {
    var imageData = this.context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data
}
```

You can also use the event object to access to DOM node as already pointed out, but this way you’ll have access from anywhere, not just event handlers.

Comment: I'd advice using a different name, since the context is a React thing too

Answer (score 36):

In accordance to React16 You can use `React.createRef()`

```
class ColorPicker extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.colorPickerRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.context = this.colorPickerRef.current.getContext('2d');
}

render() {
   return (
      <canvas ref={this.colorPickerRef} />
   )
}
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't rated high enough IMO. Thanks =]

Answer (score 18):

Here is the answer with react hooks:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export function Canvas() {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const canvas = ref.current.getContext('2d')
      // do something here with the canvas
    }
  }, [])

  return <canvas ref={ref} />
}
```

### TypeScript

And if you're using TypeScript:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export function Canvas() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const canvas = ref.current.getContext('2d')
      // do something here with the canvas
    }
  }, [])

  return <canvas ref={ref} />
}
```

### On Mount

If you only want to do something with the canvas instance once (when the component "mounts") you're probably better off doing it with `useCallback`. This way, your effect won't run twice in React Strict Mode.

```
import { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'

export function Canvas() {
  const refCallback = useCallback((canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    // do something here with the canvas
  }, [])
  return <canvas ref={refCallback} />
}
```

Comment: If you are using Typescript use this: `const ref: RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement> = useRef(null);`

Comment: That's a useful addition. I updated my example, using generics instead.

Comment: I tried your "On Mount" solution using `useCallback`, but hot reload doesn't work on NextJS, probably because it doesn't get cleaned up properly. It only gets called again.

Comment: Hooks get called again with fast refresh: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#fast-refresh-and-hooks

Answer (score 1):

It should just be accessing the target of the click

```
colorStripClick: function(e) {
  var ctx = e.target.getContext('2d')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
colorStripClick: function (e) {
    var context = e.currentTarget.getContext('2d');
    // your code
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/22307/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the React way to remove a canvas from your component:

`const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas); 
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

As long as you can target the DOM Node the react way, you can pretty much access the Canvas Rendering API.